# CentOS 7 acl not working for apache

Tags: apache-2.2, access-control-list, cgi, centos7

I want to access a user's directory from a cgi script.  I set the acl on the directory successfully but the script still gets "Permission denied" when trying to access that directory.  I su'd to apache and have the same problem (so it is not a webserver/script issue).  What am I missing?

```
# getfacl /home/pmedrano/Maildir/cur/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/pmedrano/Maildir/cur/
# owner: pmedrano
# group: pmedrano
user::rwx
user:apache:r-x
group::---
group:apache:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache:r-x
default:group::---
default:group:apache:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---

# su -s /bin/bash apache
bash-4.2$ ls /home/pmedrano/Maildir/cur/
ls: cannot access /home/pmedrano/Maildir/cur/: Permission denied
bash-4.2$ whoami
apache
bash-4.2$ getfacl /home/pmedrano/Maildir/cur/
getfacl: /home/pmedrano/Maildir/cur/: Permission denied
bash-4.2$
```

Comment: What do the permissions look like on:/home/pmedrano/Maildir and higher in the directory tree?

Comment: They were standard, but I just did "setfacl -m u:apache:rx" for pmedrano & Maildir and now apache can access cur, but apache can also now see the files in those two directories (but not the file contents).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've got **SELinux** enabled - that prevents Apache from accessing your Maildir regardless of permissions.

You can either

1. Disable SELinux altogether in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` - not recommended
2. Give Apache access to the Maildir files - check out `audit2allow` tool

Be aware that misconfiguring SELinux may have a negative impact on your server's security.

Comment: SELinux is not even installed on this box.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it comes by default with CentOS 7 and often catches unsuspecting users. Never mind, I see you already resolved the problem.